# How to create a bmesh from a list of vertices

Tags: python, blender

In blender i can make a mesh "me" from a list of vertices like that:

```
me = bpy.data.meshes.new("name") 
me.from_pydata(vertices,[],[])
```

But this function does not exist for a bmesh. What i would like to do is

```
bme=bmesh.new()
bme.from_pydata(vertices,[],[])
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A slightly modified version of the bmesh template would give you

```
import bpy
import bmesh

myvertexlist = [[2,2,2],[4,4,4],[6,6,6],[8,8,8]]

# Get the active mesh
me = bpy.context.object.data

# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.new()   # create an empty BMesh
bm.from_mesh(me)   # fill it in from a Mesh

# Modify the BMesh, can do anything here...
for newvert in myvertexlist:
    bm.verts.new(newvert)

# also add bm.edges and bm.faces

# Finish up, write the bmesh back to the mesh
bm.to_mesh(me)
bm.free()  # free and prevent further access
```

Comment: Thank you. The modifying bmesh lines could probably do the job. But isn't there an equivalent to the "mesh.from_pydata" function for bmesh? I would like not to make any detour over the regular meshes and also avoid looping over the vertices.

Comment: I don't believe there is a from_pydata in bmesh. In the end there isn't a big difference between your code looping over the verts to add them or a built-in function doing it for you.

Comment: There's actually a huge difference in that internal code can often run much faster and more efficiently than pure Python code, especially over large datasets.
See post [here](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?391847-Efficient-copying-of-vertex-coords-to-and-from-numpy-arrays) and referenced [article](http://blog.michelanders.nl/2016/02/copying-vertices-to-numpy-arrays-in_4.html).